# Aggregate vector by its content

Tags: r, vector, aggregate

I have created the vector:

```
z = c(1,1,2,3,3)
```

Now I want to create a function that will convert my vector to:

```
z = c(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
unique(z)
```